# Is it possible to use $ as part of attribute name using xpath

Tags: html, xpath

I need to find an element but the only unique attribute contains **$** symbol.

Here is HTML:

```
<tr class="v-grid-row v-grid-row-stripe v-grid-row-has-data" style="WIDTH: 2269px; LEFT: 0px; TOP: 26px" $H="528">
    <td class=v-grid-cell style="HEIGHT: 26px; WIDTH: 48px" colSpan=1>
        <button class=v-nativebutton type=button __eventBits="1"></button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I tried this xpath expression:

```
//tr[@$H='528']/td/button
```

But I get Error: Bad token: **$H**

Is there a way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, dollar signs are not allowed in XML names. (HTML may tolerate them, but XPath was defined to operate on XML).